# How to access a variable in a nmake conditional?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, nmake

I'm having trouble accessing an environmental variable in a [nmake conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh.aspx). I've tried the following, and they all result in some sort of syntax error at the ***`!IF`***. I've also tried all the ***`==`*** variants:

```
!IF $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) = "x86"
LIB_SRCS = $(LIB_SRCS) rdrand.cpp
!ENDIF

!IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% = "x86"
LIB_SRCS = $(LIB_SRCS) rdrand.cpp
!ENDIF

!IF [$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) = "x86"]
LIB_SRCS = $(LIB_SRCS) rdrand.cpp
!ENDIF

!IF [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% = "x86"]
LIB_SRCS = $(LIB_SRCS) rdrand.cpp
!ENDIF
```

For example, using `!IF $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE) = "x86"` results in `test.nmake(30) : fatal error U1023: syntax error in expression`. Line 30 is the ***`!IF`***.

MSDN's [Makefile Preprocessing Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh.aspx) page is a teaser, and it does not tell me how to form the expression (or I have not been able to locate it).

How do I access a variable in a nmake conditional?

---

If I follow qxg's suggestion, then the code in the block is not executed:

```
!IF "$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)" = "x86"
LIB_SRCS = $(LIB_SRCS) rdrand.cpp
!ENDIF
```

In fact, printing `"$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)"` with `!MESSAGE` shows it should match. And placing a ***`XXX`*** in the block to cause a failure does not produce an error.

---

And the following is the dump of the variables:

```
C:\Users\Test>nmake /P

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

MACROS:
...
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
           OS = Windows_NT
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
!IF "$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)" == "x86"
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to @qxg correct answer.

#1) In OP's comparison, they used a single '='.
From the [NMAKE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/makefile-preprocessing?view=msvc-170):

```
To compare two strings, use the equality (==) operator
```

#2) The arguments to !IF must be a constant expression, and putting things in quotes facilitates that.  Even if you know that your environment variable evaluates to a number, !IF will treat "$(VAR)" as a constant and will fail for $(VAR) without quotes, which will be seen as a variable.

#3) If you know that 'VAR' holds a number, the following might work for you (Note that 0 is synonymous with a variable that does not exist OR a non-numeric value.):

```
!IF [exit /b $(VAR)] == 0
```