# Checking environment variables value in Makefile WIndows

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

I want to check if my environment variable is set, but this doesn't work.

```
!IFDEF VAL
    echo %VAL%
!ELSE
    echo "NOT SET"
!ENDIF
```

I know that on linux you can use ifeq, but there is no such thing in the windows makefile. Please help.

Edit: I use nmake from cl2022 in cmd.

Comment: Are you trying to use `make` with `cmd` or what? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852290/how-to-access-a-variable-in-a-nmake-conditional; note that `nmake` is rather different from GNU `make` which is what you typically get out of the box on Linux.

Comment: ```!IF "$(VAL)" != ""
    echo %VAL%
!ELSE
 echo "NOT SET"
!ENDIF ``` This always goes into else, even if val is defined

Comment: !IF [exit /b $(VAR)] == 0 and this is always true

Comment: I just want to check if that variable is defined, I don't care what its value is